# Part of Birkhoff's theorem for varieties of groups in Robinson's book.

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

This is **Exercise 2.3.4** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. My universal algebra is a little rusty, so [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3590724/104041) is not what I'm looking for; besides, I ought to be able to use tools given in Robinson's book.

### The Details:

On page 56, *ibid.*,

> Let $F$ be a free group on a countably infinite set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ and let $W$ be a nonempty subset of $F$. If $w=x_{i_1}^{l_1}\dots x_{i_r}^{l_r}\in W$ and $g_1,\dots, g_r$ are elements of a group $G$, we define the *value* of the word $w$ at $(g_1,\dots,g_r)$ to be $w(g_1,\dots,g_r)=g_1^{l_1}\dots g_{r}^{l_r}$. The subgroup of $G$ generated by all values in $G$ of words in $W$ is called the *verbal subgroup* of $G$ determined by $W$,
>
> $$W(G)=\langle w(g_1,g_2,\dots) \mid g_i\in G, w\in W\rangle.$$

On page 57, *ibid.*,

> If $W$ is a set of words in $x_1, x_2, \dots$ and $G$ is any group, a normal subgroup $N$ is said to be *$W$-marginal* in $G$ if
>
> $$w(g_1,\dots, g_{i-1}, g_ia, g_{i+1},\dots, g_r)=w(g_1,\dots, g_{i-1}, g_i, g_{i+1},\dots, g_r)$$
>
> for all $g_i\in G, a\in N$ and all $w(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r)$ in $W$. This is equivalent to the requirement: $g_i\equiv h_i \mod N, (1\le i\le r)$, always implies that $w(g_1,\dots, g_r)=w(h_1,\dots, h_r)$.
>
> [The] $W$-marginal subgroups of $G$ generate a normal subgroup which is also $W$-marginal. This is called *the $W$-marginal of $G$* and is written $$W^*(G).$$

On page 58, *ibid.*,

> If $W$ is a set of words in $x_1, x_2, \dots $, the class of all groups $G$ such that $W(G)=1$, or equivalently $W^*(G)=G$, is called the *variety* $\mathfrak{B}(W)$ determined by $W$.

### The Question:

> Prove that every variety is closed with respect to forming subgroups, images, and subcartesian products.

### Thoughts:

This must have made sense to me at least two times (although it took some searching to confirm it):

- When I read Chapter 11 of *"A Course in Universal Algebra"* by Burris and Sankappanavar several years ago; this is tackled, as I said, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3590724/104041).
- When I read Chapter 12 of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"* a few months ago. This is how I found out it's part of Birkhoff's Theorem. In the proof there, however, is the ever-infuriating "It is clear"; also: images are not covered.${}^\dagger$

I don't know why I've been stuck on it the last few days, but I have, so here I am.

My rough understanding is that the processes of taking of subgroups, images, and subcartesian products mean they each inherit the words in $W$, but this "understanding" is nothing more, I fear, than a restatement of the question.

The chapter in Robinson's book is on free groups and presentations, so I've looked in many of my combinatorial group theory books, like Magnus *et al*., but the theorem is nowhere obvious.

(I hope this is enough context.)

I'm looking for something more than "it is clear" and less than a deep dive into [universal-algebra](/questions/tagged/universal-algebra).

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$ But quotients are, which, I suppose, is equivalent . . . I don't know.

Comment: The hard part of Birkhoff's Theorem is that not only is any class closed under products, subgroups, and homomorphic images a variety, but that in fact the vareity generated by a class $X$ is the collection of all homomorphic images of subgroups of direct products of elements of $X$, i.e. that $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{P}(X))$. Hence it being calls "Birkhoff's HSP Theorem."

Comment: It's a little obnoxious that he uses "subcartesian products" here. Every subgroup of a cartesian product can be realized as a subcartesian product of the the projections: if $S\leq\mathrm{Cr}G_{\lambda}$, then $S$ is a subcartesian product of $\mathrm{Cr}\pi_{\lambda}(S)$. So closure under subgroups and cartesians is both equivalent and less mentally taxing.

Comment: Yes, "images" is equivalent to quotient, provided you throw in "isomorphic copies of".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W$ be a set of words, let $\mathfrak{W}$ be the corresponding variety.

The key observation is that for any word $w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, any groups $G$ and $K$, and any morphism $f\colon G\to K$, $$f(w(g_1,\ldots,g_n))=w(f(g_1),\ldots,f(g_n)).$$
This follows because $w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is just an element of the free group $F_n$, and the value of $w$ is the image of that element under the unique homomorphism $F_n\to G$ induced by the assignment $x_i\mapsto g_i$; while $f(w(g_1,\ldots,g_n))$ is therefore the value of $w$ under the unique morphism $F_n\to K$ induced by the composite assignment $x_i\mapsto g_i\mapsto f(g_i)$.

In particular, for any groups $G$ and $K$ and any morphism $f\colon G\to K$, we have $f(W(G))\subseteq W(K)$, since the image of the generators of $W(G)$ lie in $W(K)$.

Note that any class of groups that is closed under subgroups will be closed under subcartesian products if and only if it is closed under cartesian (arbitrary unrestricted) products. Indeed, if $\{G_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a family of groups in the class, the cartesian product is a special case of the subcartesian product, and the subcartesian product is a subgroup of the cartesian.

So it suffices to show that: (i) If $\{G_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a family of groups in $\mathfrak{W}$, then $\mathop{\mathrm{Cr}}\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda} G_{\lambda}$ lies in $\mathfrak{W}$; (ii) that if $G\in\mathfrak{W}$ and $H\leq G$, then $H\in\mathfrak{W}$; and (iii) that if $G\in\mathfrak{W}$ and $\varphi\colon G\to K$ is a surjective homomorphism of groups, then $K\in\mathfrak{W}$.

1. Assume that $\{G_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a family of groups with $G_{\lambda}\in\mathfrak{W}$ for every $\lambda$; that means that $W(G_{\lambda})=\{e_{\lambda}\}$ for every $\lambda$. Let $w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in W$, and let $\mathbf{y}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_n\in \mathop{\mathrm{Cr}}\limits_{\lambda\in\lambda}G_{\lambda}$. We want to show that $w(\mathbf{y}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_n)=e$. Indeed, recall that the operations are componentwise; thus, if $\pi_{\lambda}$ is the projection on the $\lambda$ coordinate, which means that $\pi_{\lambda}(\mathbf{y}_i) = \mathbf{y}_i(\lambda)\in G_{\lambda}$ (since the elements of the cartesian product are functions from $\Lambda$ to $\cup G_i$ with the value at $\lambda$ in $G_{\lambda}$). Therefore, for each $\lambda$,
   $$\begin{align*}
   \pi_{\lambda}(w(\mathbf{y}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_n)) &= w(\pi_{\lambda}(\mathbf{y}_1),\ldots,\pi_{\lambda}(\mathbf{y}_n))\\
   &= w(\mathbf{y}_1(\lambda),\ldots,\mathbf{y}_n(\lambda))\\
   &\in W(G_{\lambda}).
   \end{align*}$$
   But $W(G_{\lambda})=\{e_{\lambda}\}$ because $G_{\lambda}\in\mathfrak{W}$, so $\pi_{\lambda}(w(\mathbf{y}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_n) = e_{\lambda}$. As this occurs for every $\lambda$, we conclude that $w(\mathbf{y}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_n)=e$. Thus, $W(\mathop{\mathrm{Cr}} G_{\lambda}) \in \mathfrak{W}$, as desired.
2. Let $G\in\mathfrak{W}$, $H\leq G$. If $w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in W$, and $h_1,\ldots,h_n\in H$, then $h_i\in G$, so $w(h_1,\ldots,h_n)\in W(G)=\{e\}$; hence $W(H)=\{e\}$, and thus $H\in\mathfrak{W}$. Alternatively, the inclusion map $\iota\colon H\to G$ has $\iota(W(H))\subseteq W(G)=\{e\}$, hence $W(H)=\{e\}$.
3. If $G\in\mathfrak{W}$ and $f\colon G\to K$ is surjective, I claim that $f(W(G))=W(K)$. Indeed, let $w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in W$, and let $k_1,\ldots,k_n\in K$. Then there exist $g_i\in G$ such that $f(g_i)=k_1$, and hence
   $$\begin{align}
   w(k_1,\ldots,k_n) &= w(f(g_1),\ldots,f(g_n))\\
   & = f(w(g_1),\ldots,w(g_n))\\
   &\in f(W(G)).
   \end{align}$$
   Since the words $w(k_1,\ldots,k_n)$ generete $W(K)$, and $f(W(G))$ is a subgroup, it follows that $W(K)\subseteq f(W(G))$. But as we observed above, $f(W(G))\subseteq W(K)$ , giving equality. Thus, $W(K) = f(W(G))=f(\{e\}) = \{e\}$, so $W(K)=\{e\}$ and hence $K\in\mathfrak{W}$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is as clear and as helpful as always from you.

Comment: @Shaun: This was all part of background reading for my dissertation (looking at a particular construction in the context of varieties of groups), so I read though Hanna Neumann's book and many of the papers about varieties and the like up to the 80s, when it kind of fell into disfavor. So I fear this is well-trodden ground for me. Also, I am currently teaching an advanced course out of Bergman's book *An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions* (and we're about to start talking about varieties!), so I've also been thinking about how to introduce them to new people.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if I am misunderstanding the question, so my apologies if the following answer is totally missing the point. It seems like the question is essentially: given a set of words $W$, show that given $G,H\in \mathfrak B(W)$, any subgroup of $G$, homomorphic image of $G$, and semidirect product $G\ltimes H$ is also in $\mathfrak B(W)$. If that's the right understanding, then I believe the first two follow easily from writing things down.

Suppose $G\in \mathfrak{B}(W)$. If $G_1\leq G_2$, it is pretty easy to see that $W(G_1)\leq W(G_2)$  (as the generators of $W(G_1)$ are a subset of generators of $W(G_2)$ by definition), so in particular if $H\subset G$, $W(H)\leq W(G)=1$ thus $H\in \mathfrak{B}(W)$.

Similarly, if we have $\phi:G\rightarrow H$, $W(\phi(G))=\phi(W(G))=1$ by the definition of a group homomorphism, so $\phi(G)\in \mathfrak{B}(W)$.

For the semidirect product, I guess this is easiest to see from the marginal perspective somehow, but it is eluding me at the moment.

Comment: Subcartesian product is not a semidirect products. A subcartesian product is a subgroup of the cartesian product with the property that the restriction of the projections are surjective. Varieties are not generally closed under semidirect products: the semidirect product of two abelian groups need not be abelian, as witnessed by $S_3\cong C_3\rtimes C_2$. But the class of all abelian group is a variety, since it is determined by the word $[x,y]$.

Comment: Ah I wasn’t familiar with the term subcartesian and the only reference I could have with respect to groups was as a synonym of semi direct. Also good example, I didn’t think through that abelin groups are an obvious example of this notion of variety.

Comment: Robinson is a bit weird here. He uses "cartesian" for what most people call "direct product" (and a few call "unrestricted direct product"), and uses "direct product" for what most people call "restricted direct product" (or "direct sum"). So his "subcartesian product" is what most people call "subdirect product". The standard example of subdirect products in group theory is Goursat's Lemma (for a subdirect product of a product of two groups).